# SWRL rule in Protégé 4.3

Tags: ontology, protege, swrl

I want to create a new class "Adult" to my ontology by using a SWRL rule, i used this rule:

```
Person(?p), age(?p, true), greaterThan(age, 18) -> Adult(?p)
```

I also installed pellet reasoner to execute this rule but the class is not created after reasonig.
So what is the correct way to use swrl rules in protege 4.3 to add new classes to the ontology?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you did **not** create an  `Adult` class in your ontology? If my understanding is correct then you misunderstand the meaning of `Adult(?p)`. It will **not** create the class `Adult`. Rather, assuming the class `Adult` already exists. it will result in the individual `p` to be of type `Adult`.

Comment: NO i have already created the class Adult  and i want to assign this rule to it, Something like EquivalentTo. Sorry i'm a beginner in web semantics that's why i haven't understand wel